# Java API's methods not overridden, does the class extending this API use that method default implementation?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, overriding

I have a question when importing Java API's and extending them, to make our classes act like them. Then for few methods not overridden, could they use default implementation provided by the API or do we need to override few methods and give our implementation, when can we use default implementation or overridden implementation ? What kind of API's could we use for default implementation ?

Comment: I think you need to supply an example, your question doesn't make much sense.  If you import a library and extend a class, only *YOUR USES* of that class get extended (and overridden methods) the library remains unchanged.  If you want a default implementation, use the default class.

Comment: If you subclass e.g. `ArrayList` and override the `get(int index)` method to do something different, then all other methods that you haven't overridden are handled by the `ArrayList` class code. --- You should however be aware that the result can be weird, because if you make `get(int index)` return something that isn't in the list, then someone who iterates the list will be baffled by the discrepancy. So **beware** what you're doing.